# Explain why "normal" is a good use of the word for normal extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, terminology, galois-theory

An extension $L:K$ is *normal* if each $\alpha \in L$ has minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha} \in K[x]$ that splits over $L$.

According to a book I'm reading on Galois theory, *normal* is one of the most overworked words in mathematics but that it will be seen that *normal* extensions make good use of the word.

This undoubtedly has to do with *normal* subgroups (right?). But I'm trying to state it in a good way.

A Galois extension $L:K$ is finite, normal, and separable, which sets up a Galois correspondence between intermediate fields $M$ and subgroups $\Gamma(L:M) \subseteq \Gamma(L:K)$.

The extension $L:M$ is always finite, normal, and separable, while the extension $M : K$ is finite and separable but not necessarily normal.

The extension $M : K$ is normal if and only if $\Gamma(L:M)$ is a normal subgroup of $\Gamma(L:K)$. In this case, $\Gamma(M:K) \cong \Gamma(L:K)/\Gamma(L:M)$.

Does this essentially explain why *normal* is a good use of the word?

Comment: normal is probably the most overburdened word in algebra. But I think that this is a case where normal is actually applied well, for the reason you've provided.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun The book is *A Course in Galois Theory* by Garling, which is excellent.

Comment: Question: which terminology came first historically? Normal extensions or normal subgroups? Perhaps your question may be the wrong way round!

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes, looks like it is the other way around! Richard Borcherds briefly mentions the terminology in [this lecture](https://youtu.be/zAqVrdNE81g?t=1092) on normal extensions.